# Add In-app Purchase Item after app available on App store without updating app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, in-app-purchase

I uploaded one of my app before couple of weeks and it is available on the App store now. It has 2 In- app purchase. In app purchase logic is totally from remote server as we wanted to add new pack without updating binary file so we did everything on server side.

So, here is my actual question. Now I want to add new pack. so here is my confusion/question.

I made on inventory.xml file for all the In app purchase id for validating in app id. and I am displaying only those Items which are valid from App store.

Also, when user purchase any pack I am downloading contents from the server and they will have new pack after successful purchase.

So, how do I make it available to Apple for submission purposes without also making it available to the general public?  That is, if I add the new pack to the inventory.xml file which lists all the packs, everyone will be able to see it before Apple even approves it.  But if I don't add the new pack to inventory.xml, then Apple will have nothing to look at in order to approve it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer for this question from other sources. So I am posting it here what I have found and I believe that is the correct answer. This is my opinion it may be wrong..

So, in my situation I can add new item in my inventory.xml file as well as in iTunes account and put it new item for the review.

The reason why General public (users) will not see my new pack because I have only show valid products which I got from SKProductResponse. So in the review process it will not be valid product and it would not show in the list of available items to the users.

Now, We and Apple tester can see it because we both are using In-app test user account to test new items and I believe In-app test user account returns all the product as valid.

So, from this flow I decided to move forward with this and hopefully it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your update.  Have you try to submit new IAP without adding to inventory.xml?  I'm asking so because my app is not yet configured in the same way as you do.  So my general users will see the pending IAP but not able to purchase them (that is odd).

Answer (score 2):

When you submit new in-app purchases to Apple, you upload screenshots and descriptions of the new content to iTunes Connect. That should be all they need for review, and you can wait to update your inventory.xml file until they have approved the new content.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But aren't apple test In-app purchase item. If I will not add my new item in my inventory.xml file then how it will display in app and also we are not able to test it at our side to make sure everything working fine..

Comment: They don't really "test" it, they just make sure it's not porn or something.

Comment: @Jonathan. Thanks for the answer. But how can they make sure as There is nothing in the In app items. I am downloading contents from the server when user purchase packs. So I guess Apple should be interested to see what I am downloading when user purchase packs. I can't believe they are not testing it. If I don't add my new pack in my inventory then Actual app doesn't have anything and no one able to test neither Apple nor my team.

Comment: Damned if I know. :) Apple's review process is a black box.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel that your question has been answered :)

Comment: @ashack I am sorry but this is not right answer. I got answer from other sources I will put it here soon to help you guys.